# Register a MediatR pipeline with void/Task response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cqrs, mediatr

My command:

```
public class Command : IRequest { ... }
```

My handler:

```
public class CommandHandler : IAsyncRequestHandler<Command> { ... }
```

My pipeline registration (not using open generics):

```
services.AddTransient<IPipelineBehavior<Command>, MyBehavior<Command>>();
```

However this doesn't work: `Using the generic type 'IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>' requires 2 type arguments.` And same error for `MyBehavior`.

[The docs](http://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki/Behaviors#registering-pipeline-behaviors) mention the [`Unit` struct](http://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/master/src/MediatR/Unit.cs). How do I use it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Mickaël Derriey pointed out, MediatR already defines [IRequest](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/master/src/MediatR/IRequest.cs#L6), [IRequestHandler](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/master/src/MediatR/IRequestHandler.cs#L23) and [IAsyncRequestHandler](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/master/src/MediatR/IAsyncRequestHandler.cs#L25) to not return a value if it isn't needed.

If you look at [IRequest](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/master/src/MediatR/IRequest.cs#L6), you can see it actually inherits from `IRequest<Unit>`, which means when you process `Command`, your pipeline behavior `MyBehavior` will return the `Unit` struct as the response by default without needing to specify an explicit response for your `Command`.

As an example:

```
public class Command : IRequest { ... }
public class CommandHandler : IAsyncRequestHandler<Command> { ... }

services.AddTransient<IPipelineBehavior<Command,Unit>, MyBehavior<Command,Unit>>();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I've figured it out, and it seems to work so far.

```
public class Command : IRequest<Unit> { ... }
public class CommandHandler : IAsyncRequestHandler<Command, Unit> { ... }

services.AddTransient<IPipelineBehavior<Command,Unit>, MyBehavior<Command,Unit>>();
```

Comment: MediatR defines the specific [`IRequest`](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/master/src/MediatR/IRequest.cs#L6), [`IRequestHandler`](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/master/src/MediatR/IRequestHandler.cs#L23) and [`IAsyncRequestHandler`](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/master/src/MediatR/IAsyncRequestHandler.cs#L25) types for the cases where you don't want to return a value. Same behavior as specifying `Unit` as a return type, the semantics are closer to what you try to achieve since you don't need to return a `Unit` instance in the handler.