# IRequestHandler return void

Tags: c#, async-await, task, cqrs, mediatr

Please see the code below:

```
public class CreatePersonHandler
    : IRequestHandler<CreatePersonCommand,bool>
{
    public async Task<bool> Handle(CreatePersonCommand message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

It works as expected i.e. the hander is reached and returns true.  How do I deal with the scenario where the handler returns nothing? I want to do this:

```
public async void Handle(CreatePersonCommand message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    //don't return anything
}
```

I have spent the last two hours Googling this.  For example, I have looked here: [Register a MediatR pipeline with void/Task response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385619/register-a-mediatr-pipeline-with-void-task-response) and here: https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/issues/230.

Comment: `public async Task Handle`

Comment: `async Task`, basically (the number of times you should use `async void` is approximately, but *not quite*, zero)

Comment: Please see more details here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Generally speaking, if a Task based method does not return anything you can return a [completed Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.completedtask?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
    public Task Handle(CreatePersonCommand message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Now, in MediatR terms a value *needs* te be returned. In case of no value you can use `Unit`:

```
    public Task<Unit> Handle(CreatePersonCommand message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(Unit.Value);
    }
```

or, in case of some async code somewhere

```
    public async Task<Unit> Handle(CreatePersonCommand message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);

        return Unit.Value;
    }
```

The class signature should then be:

```
public class CreatePersonHandler : IRequestHandler<CreatePersonCommand>
```

which is short for

```
public class CreatePersonHandler : IRequestHandler<CreatePersonCommand, Unit>
```

Comment: Thanks.  This class is inheriting from a base class, which looks like this: public class IdentifiedCommandHandler<T, R> : IRequestHandler<IdentifiedCommand<T, R>, R>
        where T : IRequest<R>.  Is there anything I can do here? i.e. I need to have a second generic parameter.

Comment: How can I test that the function completed successfully using: Unit.Value; ?

Comment: @w0051977 it has no use to test `Unit.Value`  since it is the MediatR representation of a Task based void. If you look at the source code you'll see it has [a default value assigned](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/master/src/MediatR/Unit.cs#L14).

Comment: Thank you.  Would you just not test this method? The method is contained in a class with no instance variables and it does not return anything.

Comment: 2023 update: Starting with v12.x, `IRequest` no longer inherits from `IRequest<Unit>`, meaning all methods with return type `Task<Unit>` should be changed to just `Task` and `return Unit.Value` to just `return;` 
Reference: https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki/Migration-Guide-11.x-to-12.0#void-handlers-irequest-and-irequesthandler

Comment: It should be noted here, that if you don't use async/await, you can return `Unit.Task`, which is non-allocating (because it caches one single completed task that contains `Unit.Value`)

Answer (score 18):

In `CreatePersonCommand` , `IRequest` shouldn't have any response type specified :

```
public record CreatePersonCommand : IRequest
```

And in `PersonCommandHandler`, `IRequestHandler` would be like this :

```
public class PersonCommandHandler: IRequestHandler<PersonCommandHandler>
```

And then in your `handle` method :

```
public async Task<Unit> Handle(CreatePersonCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Some Code 

    return Unit.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Workaround solution for anyone who doesn't want to use Unit for some reason. You can create class named as VoidResult or EmptyResult then use it as return for all requests that returns nothing.

```
public class CreatePersonHandler : IRequestHandler<CreatePersonCommand, VoidResult>
```

Comment: And that is exactly what`Unit` does. Am I wrong?

Comment: You are not wrong, but I could see someone wanting to use something that makes it more clear. `Unit` doesn't exactly scream "Doesn't return a value" to most people.

Comment: yes, you are right. @Orace

Answer (score 2):

There's another abstract class named [`AsyncRequestHandler`](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki#request-types) that is a wrapper class for a handler that asynchronously handles a request and does not return a response.

```cs
public class CreatePersonHandler : AsyncRequestHandler<CreatePersonCommand>
{
    protected override Task Handle(CreatePersonCommand request, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        // don't return anything
    }
}
```